# How to increase the Advertised Bandwidth of Tor onion router (OR)?

Tags: exit-relays, bandwidth, atlas

I am operating Tor relay as an exit on 10 MegaBytes/s speed network. But when checking from http://atlas.torproject.org, it shows only 700KBps Advertised Bandwidth. How to increase this bandwidth?

Comment: For how long is your relay online? Have you set `DirPort` in your `torrc`?

Comment: Its been online for 14 hours..but it has been used in the past also..I have set DirPort in the torrc.

Answer (score 6):

Advertised bandwidth as reported by atlas and globe is really what is
observed as of far. Your relay has only been up for four days, and as your
relay proves its reliability and speed, advertised bandwidth will go up.

https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-relays/2014-June/004711.html

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer. According to the link provided advertised bandwidth has little to do with the options in your torrc. From the link in answer: "Advertised bandwidth is not what you put in torrc. The bandwidth options in torrc are meant to allow you to throttle your traffic, so that bandwidth usage is still reasonable. Eventually, as your relay matures, advertised bandwidth should closely match what you've put in your torrc."

Answer (score 2):

In your torrc, there are 2 keys that determine your advertised relay bandwidth:

- `RelayBandwidthRate`  - Sets/limits how much bandwidth you allow for
  relaying.
- `MaxAdvertisedBandwidth` - May not be higher than
  *RelayBandwidthRate*. If you don't have this entry, then your *RelayBandwidthRate* is advertised.

Comment: I have set both the keys.I have set RelayBandwidthRate at 5 MBps and MaxAdvertisedBandwidth to 10 MBps.

Comment: Your MaxAdvertisedBandwidth should not be higher than your RelayBandwidthRate.

Comment: I have configured my torrc file as follows:<br/>    
ControlPort 9051<br/>  
DataDirectory /home/***/.tor <br/> 
DirPort 9030  <br/>
DirReqStatistics 0  <br/>
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0  <br/>
Log notice stdout  <br/>
Nickname ubuntu123  <br/>
ORPort 9001  <br/>
RelayBandwidthBurst 1073741824 <br/> 
RelayBandwidthRate 104857600 <br/> 
SocksPort 9050 <br/> Still I am not able to advertise my bandwidth fully ?What can be done ?

Comment: Check those values. Your `burst` is 1 billion and your `rate` is 100 million. These are _bytes_, not _bits_. Try 10485760 for both, or just leave out `burst`.

Comment: I set 10485760 for both but still its showing only 1 MBPs advertised bandwidth.

Comment: I get 108.67KB/s "advertised" while I set `RelayBandwidthRate 2100 KB` and no MaxAdBW in my torrc. Was under the impression that advertised bandwidth is (partly?) based on benchmarks from others, or isn't it?

Comment: Then I don't know, sorry. For me, advertised bandwidth on Atlas is what I have in my torrc. The thing that is (partly) based on measurements (by self + others?) is the _consensus_ _weight_.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this Advertised bandwidth value calculated by the Tor network instead of defined by your torrc config file?

When i have setup new relay, https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html shown "Advertised Bandwidth 0 B/s", i think that this value is not always directly equal to the limits set in torrc file, at least in a first days after setting up new relay, see the https://blog.torproject.org/lifecycle-new-relay

> A new relay, assuming it is reliable and has plenty of bandwidth, goes
> through four phases: the unmeasured phase (days 0-3) where it gets
> roughly no use, the remote-measurement phase (days 3-8) where load
> starts to increase